# get cookies from url in webview android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get cookie from URl in android web view. but always get null..
here is my code

```java
 public String getCookie(WebView mWebView, String siteName,String cookieName){
        String CookieValue = null;

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
        String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);
        String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
        for (String ar1 : temp ){
            if(ar1.contains(cookieName)){
                String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
                CookieValue = temp1[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return CookieValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);` before the visit (loadUrl).

If the problem isn't that, I don't think you have that cookie. You can try to log `cookies` variable to the console for being sure the cookie is really exists.